# ParseConfig not working

Tags: scons

For some strange reason, `ParseConfig` does not work, while manually invoking the commands inside work fine.
The following:

```
test = ['sh', '-c', 'PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/mylib pkg-config --cflags --libs mylib']
env.ParseConfig( test )
print env.get( "CPPPATH" )
env.MergeFlags( env.backtick(test) )
print env.get( "CPPPATH" )
```

gives me:

```
None
['/mylib/include']
```

I seem to miss something obvious here - but cannot find what.

Comment: The above hack is needed because `os.environ['PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR'] = "/mylib"` is ignored by `env.ParseConfig( test )`.